# Updating linked server with temp table join

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, linked-server

I am performing the following operation:

```
Update A set A.col1 = B.col1
From LinkedServer.LinkedDatabase.dbo.remoteTable A
JOIN #localTempTable B on B.column = A.primaryKeyColumn
```

The performance is terrible and the query takes what seems to be forever, 
given that i can't just create a table to store the temp table data in, what can I do in SQL Server 2014 to improve this? I am considering running the query from the linked server instead.

Comment: Is SSIS a possibility?  Linked Server performance can be unpredictable and end up in RBAR DML. I would definitely find another way of doing what you need to do if it involves a lot of data.

Comment: Why can’t you create a temp table to store the data?

Answer (score 1):

current query

```
Update linked 
   set linked.col1 = local.col1
  From LinkedServer.LinkedDatabase.dbo.remoteTable linked
  JOIN #localTempTable local 
         on local.column = linked.primaryKeyColumn
```

It is typically better to perform the write operation locally
Here you are both reading from and writing to the linked server

My recommendation is if you are going to create #localTempTable then do so on LinkedServer.  Have a session on the LinkedServer and link to local to populate #localTempTable but #localTempTable is now on LinkedServer.  Flop the link.

```
insert into #linkedLocalTempTable 
select ... 
from Local.LinkedDatabase...
```

Please post the query to populate #localTempTable
If you use that table for other stuff then flopping stuff around may not be and option